# Observer pattern or some other pattern

Tags: java, observablecollection, addeventlistener, observable

I was in the process of developing a small utility which has to be developed in pretty haste :(. So little time for experiment:(. Actually the utility has three main wings. Two of them are populating some different data pools.And the third need to sit and listen on one of the data pool and starts its functioning the moment that data pool is populated by an additional data. Obviously all thee wings are running as three different threads. Now my question is for the third wing. What should be the best way to go for it. Should I use observer and observable pattern or there are other alternative available in Java(yeah some ready to use f/w is required).
Hasn't done much R&D.Sorry but as I said little time for experiment.So any other pattern that strikes you something like listener pattern?

Thanks,
Mawia

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and in your third wing, you try to poll from the queue and it will block until some element gets added. And it is a thread-safe structure.